# Как ограничить выполнение функции mousemove 1 раз в секунду?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день есть такая функция

```
$('body').mousemove(function(evt){
    if(evt.target.classList[0] == 'home-shadow'){
      var totalWidth = $('.home-shadow').width()
      var rect = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect()
      var x = evt.clientX - rect.left; 
      var percent = x*100 / totalWidth
      console.log(percent)

      var styleElem = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));

      styleElem.innerHTML = `#home-shadow:before {background-position: ${percent}% 50%`;
    }
  });
```

Все работает хорошо и эта функция меняет позицию фона, но проблема в том что mousemove выполняется при каждом px мышки, и так и должно работать но и за этого функция выполняется очень часто и даже мой ноут включает кулер в этот момент. Вопрос, как сделать что бы

```
styleElem.innerHTML = `#home-shadow:before {background-position: ${percent}% 50%`;
```

Имела ограничения на выполнение 1 раз в секунду?

Comment: Вводите переменную lastRunTime. И следите чтоб значение lastRunTime - Now было больше одной секунды

Comment: есть общий (более менее) подход - использовать функцию `throttle` из библиотеки `underscore`. Ну или написать свою )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
let lastRunTime = Date.now();
$('body').mousemove(function(evt){
    if(evt.target.classList[0] == 'home-shadow'){
      var totalWidth = $('.home-shadow').width()
      var rect = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect()
      var x = evt.clientX - rect.left; 
      var percent = x*100 / totalWidth
      console.log(percent)

      var styleElem = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));

      if ((lastRunTime - Date.now()) > 1000) {  
        styleElem.innerHTML = `#home-shadow:before {background-position: ${percent}% 50%`;
        lastRunTime = Date.now(); 
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: `now() возвращает количество миллисекунд` -> `..Date.now()) > 1`, эээм.. Я только проснулся, это ошибка или нет?))

Comment: Да, скорее всего ошибка, только писал об этом)

Comment: Да поменял, странно почему то поставил сначала 1000 потом убрал и поставил 1